# function savefile(); exporta padrão pra pasta downloads

Tags: javascript, html5, arquivo, javascript-eventos, exportação

Bom dia, gostaria de uma ajuda, a função está exportando direto para pasta download, eu gostaria de poder escolher em qual pastar salvar o arquivo. ainda não consegui enxergar uma solução para essa funcionalidade, agradeço a todos que se dispõem a me dar uma ajuda ou até mesmo um direcionamento, abraço!

```
function saveFile(){
var textToSave = document.getElementById("wmd-input").value;
var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:"text/plain"});
var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileName").value;

var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs+".md";
downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
downloadLink.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

downloadLink.click();
```

}